# Can not set mapboxgl.GeolocateControl()

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I can not set GeolocateControl()

It have not error, but not show Geolocate??

```js
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
    positionOptions: {
        enableHighAccuracy: true
    },
    trackUserLocation: true,
}));
```

Comment: It shows up for me when I try this locally – can you post a jsfiddle or jsbin with this behavior?

Comment: Are you running in an environment where geocoding is not available? For instance, in Chrome on an HTTP (not HTTPS) connection?

Answer (score 0):

your code is perfect but you need to have secure https connection to visible the GeolocateControl in your application.